# Python Formatting for specific dashboard

Tags: python-2.7

I am getting the output in list

```
[
(u'Shift 1', u'NURSES', u'ANITHA M.N.', u'A'), 
(u'Shift 1', u'Counsellors', u'SUSHMITHA B.', u'A'), 
(u'Shift 2', u'Counsellors', u'ALEX THOMAS MATHEW', u'B')
]
```

I want to format the output as the follows.

```
{
    name: "Shift 1",
    id: "A",
    expanded: true,
    children: [{
            name: "Counsellors",
            id: "A.1",
            children: [{
                name: "SUSHMITHA B.",
                id: "A.1.1"
            }, ]
        }, {
            name: "Nurses",
            id: "A.2",
            children: [{
                name: "ANITHA M.N",
                id: "A.2.1"
            }, ]

        },

    ]
}, {
    name: "Shift 2",
    id: "B",
    expanded: true,
    children: [{
            name: "Counsellors",
            id: "B.1",
            children: [{
                name: "ALEX THOMAS MATHEW",
                id: "B.1.1"
            }, ]
        },

    ]
},
```

The below format has to be done.
Have used the concepts of multiple group by list of tuples in python.

```
from itertools
import groupby
import pdb

L = [(u 'Shift 1', u 'NURSES', u 'ANITHA. BHARATHAN', u 'A'), (u 'Shift 1', u 'NURSES', u 'ANITHA M.N.', u 'A'), (u 'Shift 1', u 'Counsellors', u 'SUSHMITHA B.', u 'A'), (u 'Shift 2', u 'Counsellors', u 'ALEX THOMAS MATHEW', u 'B')]
for x, y in groupby(sorted(L), lambda t: t[0]):
    children = []
    for c, d in groupby(sorted(y), lambda t: t[1]):
        children.append('children: {}: {}'.format(c, ', '.join(c[2]
            for c in d)))
```

could not get the above format but getting close to it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered using classes?

Comment: No. I am doing this for odoo framework.